# linq case insensitive and trimmed comparison

Tags: c#, linq

I am using `linq` to query a table.

My query filters need to compare a few string values - this comparison is case insensitive and trimmed of white spaces, not just at the start and at the end of my strings but also in the middle eg. *"chong qing"* or *"si chuan"*. I have tried to solve this but I found it is not working.

```
string fromLocation = this.uiFromLocation.Text;
string toLocation = this.uiToLocation.Text;
fromLocation = fromLocation.Trim().ToUpper();
toLocation = toLocation.Trim().ToUpper();

 var results = from myRow in sectionsDetails.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                              where myRow.Field<string>("LocationFrom").Trim().ToUpper() == fromLocation &&
                              myRow.Field<string>("LocationTo").Trim().ToUpper() == toLocation &&
                              myRow.Field<int>("VehicleType") == vehicleType
                              orderby myRow.Field<DateTime>("ModifiedDate") descending
                              select myRow;
```

I guess

```
myRow.Field<string>("LocationFrom").Trim().ToUpper() == fromLocation
```

is not correct?

How do I make this work?

Comment: _"what is the possible cause of not working?"_ - what's not working? Details?

Comment: What it shown in debugger?

Comment: Is that there exist a way I can print ```myRow.Field<string>("LocationFrom").Trim().ToUpper()```

Comment: @Sem it runs without problem, but can't get any result, I am doubting ```myRow.Field<string>("LocationFrom").Trim().ToUpper()``` does not get the trim result, I want to trim a space in the middle of the string

Comment: @want_to_be_calm - `Trim()` only trims whitespaces at the start and end (leading and trailing) of the string... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: So is there a way I can achieve it?

Comment: what do the strings look like?

Comment: how about: `"a b  c   d".Replace(" ", "");` or `Regex.Replace("a b  c   d", @"\s", "")`

Comment: "chong qing" or "si chuan"

Comment: as per my comment above... but out of interest... why do you want to trim the space in the middle?

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia user use location from and location to to calculate the distance, some user may have different habit in typing the location name. Thanks so much. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: By the way, is there a way to print row content in linq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Trim()` only trims white spaces at the start and end (leading and trailing) of the string... See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.8)

To remove white spaces within a string you can use:

- `*str*.Replace(" ", "");`
- `Regex.Replace(*str*, @"\s", "")`

where *str* is the string.

Also consider using a comparison method such as `*str*.Equals(*str2*, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` instead of relying on `ToUpper()`. Read [How to compare strings in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings), it explains string comparison in detail.